# MySQL statement with ORDER BY lasts very long

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am using a mysql database. The query is executed directly via the workbench tool.
The query looks like following:

```
SELECT records.received, data.value 
FROM product 
       JOIN records 
            on product.productId= records.productId 
       JOIN data 
            ON records.recordId = data.recordId 
       JOIN dataTypes 
            ON data.typeId = dataTypes.typeId 
ORDER BY records.received DESC
```

The data table has 1million entries.
The execution of this statement lasts 7 seconds. The reason seems to be the ORDER BY clause.

Can someone give me a hint how to speed it up.

Edit: sorry I forgot to add the structure:

products: PK is productId   (it has only 5 entries)

records: PK is recordId and FK is productId

data: PK is dataId and FK recordId and typeId

dataTypes: PK is typeId

There is an Index on records.received and on all PK and FK.

Here is the output of EXPLAIN:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,products,const,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,const,1,"Using index
1,SIMPLE,dataTypes,const,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,const,1,"Using index"
1,SIMPLE,records,ref,"PRIMARY,productId",productId,4,const,127142,"Using where"
1,SIMPLE,data,ref,"recordId,typeId",recordId,4,top70.records.recordId,1,"Using where"
```

Comment: What indexes are defined on your table?

Comment: it seems that you can exclude table `product` from FROM CLAUSE.

Comment: How quick do you think it should be?

Comment: Sorry I added more information. I hope it to be less than 1 sec.

Comment: @danihp: how should I exclude it the product table?

Comment: @tobias, you include `product` in from clause, but, you don't use at any time any product field. Not product fields in SELECT clause, neither in OREDER BY, neither in WHERE.

Comment: there is an where clause which I have not posted as it is not increasing the execution time. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `records` ADD INDEX `index1` (`received`);
ALTER TABLE `data` ADD INDEX `index2` (`value `);
```

try to index your coloumns on which you are using where clause or selecting the coloumns

Comment: On received I have already an Index and it makes it faster. On data.value I have none index as I thought only for Where statements it is useful?

Comment: no  indexes are usefull for the coloumn to select it also affects

Comment: I added an Index it seems to get little faster. But it still too slow :(

Answer (score 0):

try to change the query to something like:

```
WHERE records.received > '2012-01-01' -- some date you are sure your values fit
ORDER BY records.received DESC
```

and compare results of EXPLAIN statement

Comment: The problem is I only know how many I want to get but not the time of the oldest.

Comment: please, provide the result of EXPLAIN

Comment: Ok, I will add it in a moment to the post above.

Comment: how many rows your query returns? is it faster with LIMIT XXX?

Comment: Yes it is much faster with LIMIT. I want to get between 5 and 3000